# nginx unable to resolve container name when deployed to ECS, works locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have a ECS configuration I am launching. However, the nginx `frontend` container is failing citing:

```
nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream “backend”
```

This works fine locally, but it seems that ECS cannot resolve the docker container names.

I am deploying using `ecs-cli`. Launch type is `EC2`. The network mode is `bridge`.

command:

```
ecs-cli compose \
--cluster mycluster \
--file docker-compose.yml \
--ecs-params ecs-params.yml service up \
--deployment-min-healthy-percent=50 --force-deployment \
--target-groups targetGroupArn=<load-balancer>,containerName=frontend,containerPort=80 \
--health-check-grace-period 60 \
--role <my-role> \
--timeout 30
```

`ecs-params.yml`

```
task_definition:
  task_role_arn: <my-arn>
  task_execution_role: <my-exec-role>
  services:
    backend:
      essential: true
      mem_reservation: 1024m
    frontend:
      essential: true
      mem_reservation: 1024m
```

`nginx.conf`:

```
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  server_tokens off;
  upstream backend_server {
        server backend:8001;
    }

  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location /api {
      proxy_pass      http://backend_server/api;
    }

  }
}
```

`docker-compose`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    image: <backend-image>
    ports:
      - 8001:8001

  frontend:
    image: <frontend-image, built locally with the nginx conf>
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Task definition:

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": <exec-role>,
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": [],
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": { <log-options>
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": [],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8001,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8001
        }
      ],
      "command": [],
      "linuxParameters": {
        "capabilities": {
          "add": null,
          "drop": null
        },
        "sharedMemorySize": null,
        "tmpfs": null,
        "devices": [],
        "maxSwap": null,
        "swappiness": null,
        "initProcessEnabled": null
      },
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [
      ],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": [],
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": [],
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": 1024,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": <backend-image>,
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": [],
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": [],
      "pseudoTerminal": false,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": false,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": false,
      "name": "backend"
    },
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": [],
      "environmentFiles": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": { <log-options>
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": [],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 80
        }
      ],
      "command": [],
      "linuxParameters": {
        "capabilities": {
          "add": null,
          "drop": null
        },
        "sharedMemorySize": null,
        "tmpfs": null,
        "devices": [],
        "maxSwap": null,
        "swappiness": null,
        "initProcessEnabled": null
      },
      "cpu": 0,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": [],
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": [],
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": 1024,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": <frontend-image>,
      "startTimeout": null,
      "firelensConfiguration": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": [],
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": [],
      "pseudoTerminal": false,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": false,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": false,
      "name": "frontend"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": null,
  "taskRoleArn": <task-role-arn>,
  "compatibilities": [
    "EXTERNAL",
    "EC2"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": <definition>,
  "family": "<my-family>",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.ecr-auth"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.17"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.21"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-ecr-pull"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [],
  "networkMode": null,
  "runtimePlatform": null,
  "cpu": null,
  "revision": 75,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

Comment: The docker-compose file is irrelevant for this issue if you aren't using the docker-compose ECS deploy feature. Please include your ECS task definition JSON in your question.

Comment: So you are using the docker-compose file for deployment. Does this end up creating multiple ECS services, or a single service with multiple containers? If you go into the task definition that is created in the AWS console you can view the JSON representation of the task definition, which is what I was asking to see.

Comment: @MarkB added. Apologies!!

Comment: You need to setup links in your task definition. See the `links` documentation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html I'm not sure how to do that via an `ecs-cli compose` deployment, since I don't use that method, but I think you would add it to your `ecs-params.yml` file.

Comment: @MarkB Docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose-ecsparams.html) seem to suggest that this is not possible. I have tried `depends_on` before, but this still results in the same error.

Answer (score 1):

@MarkB was correct. I needed to add links. The way to do this was through the `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  backend:
    image: <backend-image>
    ports:
      - 8001:8001

  frontend:
    image: <frontend-image, built locally with the nginx conf>
    links: ["backend"]
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

I also added a healthcheck to the `ecs-params.yml` to make sure that the backend was starting up before the frontend.

The reason this happens is because the ECS network bridge is a default bridge. Which does not allow containers to be resolved by their name (hence the links). I had assumed it was a user-defined bridge. More info can be found on [Dockers documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/).